# Feature Activation Error(Cannot Add Dll to GAC)

Tags: development, error, feature-activation, application-pages

We have created a feature, which has 2 application pages. One is to activate the user control and the other one is for database configuration. For the database configuration, the user has to provide the .mdf and .ldf files to restore the database.

For the restoration of a database we have used Microsoft.sqlserver.replication.dll. The feature is working fine, but when we deploy it on any other machine, at the time of activation it gives error, and the error is:

Error: Cannot add the specified assembly to the global assembly cache: Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.dll.

The feature is working fine with windows server 2008 but it throws the mentioned error on windows server 2003. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What happens when you manually add the Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.dll assembly to the problem server's GAC?

Comment: ... after removing it manually if it already existed.

Comment: When i manually add Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.dll to GAC , its overwrite the already exists dll without prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...

do your account have full administrative privileges on the production server?

Is the assembly already present in the GAC before you add? Sometimes solution deployment cannot add an assembly if its already there.

Comment: Yes the assembly already exists in the GAC.

Comment: The feature is working fine with windows server 2008 but its giving the mention error with windows server 2003 .. any idea?

Comment: yet another reason to keep development environment as close to production as possible...

Comment: The assembly is already present in the GAC in both windows server 2008 and windows server 2003 , its work fine with 2008 but give error on 2003..

Answer (score 1):

make sure that all dependencies of the Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.dll is also registered. A quick lock using Reflector reveals that these are referenced by the dll:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
- Microsoft.VisualC, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

Comment: We are creating wsp file of the feature using WSPBuilder

Comment: You still need to make sure that those references are on the target server though. If WSPBuilder does not pick them automatically you need to add them.

Comment: The feature is working fine with windows server 2008 but its giving the mention error with windows server 2003 .. any idea?

Comment: Check if the assemblies Wictor is mentioning is in the GAC plz. They could be on the 2k8 server but not on your 2k3 server.

Comment: Yes the assemblies which Wictor mentioned are already in the GAC

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using SharePoint on Windows Server 2003 and Windows server 2008. So it means you use SharePoint 2007 version (correct me if I am wrong) and not 2010.

When you deploy a feature, the referenced dlls are deployed to GAC while solution deployment (WSP that contain feature) and not feature activation, unless you write code to add dll to GAC on FeatureActivated. For 2007, you use below commands to deploy WSP

```
stsadm -o addsolution -filename YourSolution.wsp
stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
stsadm -o deploysolution -name YourSolution.wsp -immediate -allowGacDeployment -force
```

Please note the `-allowGacDeployment` and `-force` flags you will need.
If the above commands run successfully, you have your dlls in GAC and should not affect feature activation.